# How can I make Keil RealView ARM MDK (for Cortex-M3) work with BOTH retargeting(to USART) and STL?

Tags: c++, stl, arm, cortex-m, crt

I've been searching for a workaround for days. So far no luck.

What I use:

- STM32F103VET6
- J-Link
- RealView MDK-ARM v4.12
- Both C and C++ code in my program

Before I included STL in my code, everything works fine. I can retarget `printf()` and `scanf()` to USART without a problem. This is done by including `Retarget.c` that came with RV-MDK and writing my own `sendchar()` and `getkey()`. `Retarget.c` has a line that says `#pragma import(__use_no_semihosting_swi)` which demands the linker to use the retargeting version of `<cstdio>`, instead invoking the semihosting implementation.

But when I started to `#include <deque>` and `deque<int> buffer;`, it doesn't work anymore. It seems that the linker had decided that `<deque>` depends on the the semihosting `<cstdio>`, which conflicts with the retargeting code I wrote just now.

What I tried and failed:

- Get rid of `__no_semihosting_swi` and instead try to override `_sys_open()`. It doesn't work because the semihosting `<cstdio>` depends on an object file which already exports this symbol.
- Use `$super$$` and `$sub$$` syntax suggested [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0475c/CJAIABCF.html) (I think I've tried everything they provided!)
- Use "MicroLIB". It's EPIC FAIL.
- Digging into the supplied STL headers. I found NO reference to any `stdio`. And, since I can `#include <cstdio>` and still have retargeting, I don't think even an reference would make any difference.

I suspect the solution has something to do with directing the linker, but so far I haven't figured out... This is getting so frustrating!

Comment: Did you try contacting Keil/ARM support?

Comment: @Dan I haven't yet. Just now I downloaded another version of `Retarget.c` and included it in my project and suddenly the linker had no more problem with the STL. I diffed the files and found out that the "secret ingredient" seemed to be a dummy `_sys_exit()`, which wasn't there in the original(supplied) file. But this looks like I'm actually _supposed_ to tamper with the CRT! Guess I still have to ask the ARM guys...